# Azure Blob Trigger Function triggering only once when file is updated with NLog

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, nlog

I am using NLog to log the messages in azure blob storage with blob name as **dd-mm-yyyy.log**. For each and every message which I inserted into "dd-mm-yyyy.log" file, I want to call/trigger the azure blob trigger function.

For Example, if I insert 3 message in one request one after the other, then azure blob trigger function should trigger 3 times. Curranty it is trigging only 1 time.

But if I insert 3 message with 1 min difference (i.e. 1 message at 1 min), then the azure blob trigger function triggering 3 times.

**Below is the Nlog code:**

```
try
{
    //Some logic
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    LoggingHelper.Fatal($"Exception : {Convert.ToString(ex)}");
    LoggingHelper.Fatal($"InnerException : {Convert.ToString(ex.InnerException)}");
    LoggingHelper.Fatal($"Exception StackTrace: {ex.StackTrace}");
}
```

**Azure Blob trigger code:**

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("poccontainer/{name}", Connection = "")] Stream myBlob, string name, 
    ILogger log, ExecutionContext context, BlobProperties Properties)
{
    log.LogInformation($"Blob Name:{name}");
    //Logic to process the file data
}
```

I want to trigger the azure blob trigger function every time when I insert a message into **dd-mm-yyyy.log**.

**Solution which I tried but no use:**
I have added below code in the host.json file but no use.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "batchSize": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Maybe configure `batchSize="1"` in the NLog.config (Assigned together with the `BlobName="..."` and `Container="..."`). See also https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage/blob/master/src/NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage/README.md

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not using the Azure Blob Trigger for the Function at all. The blob trigger relies on a polling mechanism so timing might be the issue in your case. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#polling):

> [...] There's no guarantee that all events are captured. Under some conditions, logs may be missed.
>
> If you require faster or more reliable blob processing, consider creating a queue message when you create the blob. Then use a queue trigger instead of a blob trigger to process the blob. Another option is to use Event Grid; see the tutorial Automate resizing uploaded images using Event Grid.

I would definitely check the Event Grid Trigger in your case. Or, if order is important, the queue based trigger.

Comment: Thank you for the replay. I am new azure and if you can help with some links for how to user queue trigger instead of Azure Blob Trigger, that would be helpful...